# iPhone SDK: Load Tweets into UITableView?

Tags: iphone

I need to include a Twitter-Feature with the Tweets of my account, but I don't know how I can get my tweets and show it in a UItableView?

Please Help.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article on getting it done with JSON.
[iPhone SDK: First Steps With JSON Data Using the Twitter API](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/)

Comment: that code not working with xcode 4.3.3.. give a compiler error after fixing this it show blank tableView..any idea ..Pls tell..